# How to Import A Project Into Android Studio ?

Tags: android, android-studio, importerror

I am trying Android Studio and its not be a smooth ride so far.I am trying to import the TrivialDrive Sample Project into Android studio, I keep getting the error

```
Cannot create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive\.idea
```

If it helps I have the build.gradle in my project.

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
```

Any ideas what is wrong ?

Comment: Cannot create directory. May be you haven't right to write in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Work Space is inside the Program file's folder which is not accessible by any other application. I suggest you to create new WorkSpace in your D Drive and then import the project again.

C Drive is for System use. You should not use it for your personal use. Try to avoid using it. If you were on OS less than Windows Vista then you won't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch Android Studio for the first time, you'll see a Welcome screen that offers several ways to get started:

```
To start building a new app, click New Project.

This starts the New Project wizard, which helps you set up a project using an app template.
To import an existing Android app project, click Import Project.

Note: If you previously developed your Android project with Eclipse, you should first use the new export feature in the ADT plugin to prepare your project with the new Gradle build system. For more information, read Migrating from Eclipse.
```

For additional help using Android Studio, read Tips and Tricks.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html